# Video.js Responsiveness doesnot work on small screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have made this bin in which I am trying to make my video.js responsive. Kindly let me know how can I do that. I tried alot but on mobile view its controls always float out of the player  and doesnot stick to its place: http://jsbin.com/idinaf/627/edit

```
videojs.autoSetup();

videojs('example_video_1').ready(function(){
  console.log(this.options()); //log all of the default videojs options

   // Store the video object
  var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();
  // Make up an aspect ratio
  var aspectRatio = 264/640; 

  function resizeVideoJS(){
    var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
    myPlayer.width(width).height( width * aspectRatio );

  }

  // Initialize resizeVideoJS()
  resizeVideoJS();
  // Then on resize call resizeVideoJS()
  window.onresize = resizeVideoJS; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For smaller screens, you should use media queries to change the css of controls of player.
I did it by this way and it worked. Hope it works for you too.